# use compareTo on more specific Comparables in Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

I would like to have a more specific Comparable interface so that I can type return parameters better.  The interface currently looks like this:

```
public interface SpecialComparable<T extends SpecialComparable<T>> extends Comparable<T> {
}
```

Now when I try to sort a list of these more specific Comparables as shown below, I get an error because b is of type 'SpecialComparable' not of type 'T'.

```
public class UserClass {
    public <T extends SpecialComparable<T>> UserClass(List<SpecialComparable<T>> comparables) {
        Collections.sort(comparables, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
    }
}
```

To solve this problem, I can implement a Self method as shown below. This would solve my problem, but it looks very ugly. I would be happy if someone could find a nicer solution to the problem.

```
public interface SpecialComparable<T extends SpecialComparable<T>> extends Comparable<T> {
    T self();
}

public class UserClass {
    public <T extends SpecialComparable<T>> UserClass(List<SpecialComparable<T>> comparables) {
        Collections.sort(comparables, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b.self()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `RankCompatible` from the error message you quote doesn't appear anywhere else in the question. Can you share its definition and the code causing this error?

Comment: I don't get the point of your interface if it adds zero methods.

Comment: @Mureinik fixed it... Sorry I did a more abstract example for the question here and forgot to edit the Method name. I'm sorry. Same goes for the camelCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your problem just here?

```
public <T extends specialComparable<T>> userClass(List<specialComparable<T>> comparables) {
```

You have a `List<specialComparable<specialComparable<?>>>`. That double nesting is presumably not the intention.

Your signature should just be

```
public <T extends specialComparable<T>> userClass(List<T> comparables) {
```

FWIW, this interface seems useless since it adds no methods to the regular `Comparable`. The method is also fairly redundant. You can simply call this on any list of `Comparable`s.

```
listOfComparables.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which has fixed the problem. 
I know this interface doesn't add methods. But it makes a difference whether you get a Comparable or something more specific as a return in large projects. For me it's easier to understand parameters etc. when they are more specific because I can get informations out of their name. 
Also, in the given case, there are special requirements for the implementation of the compare method. To distinguish them from the normal ones, the interface is used. 
But in summary, it only serves the purpose of readability.

Comment: @Mai65 you get more info out of the name, but now any methods accepting SpecialComparable cannot accept a regular Comparable (e.g. string), because it doesn't implement that interface. Not worth it, IMO. Interfaces should have methods.